# Beautiful Soup get_text() output in regular expression

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some info from a webpage. I am using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)'s get_text method to get the text, but when I try to pass that text through a regular expression, nothing is being returned.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "http://www.somesite.com"
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
info = {}
info['description'] = page.get_text()
print info['description'] #this works fine
print re.match(r'.',info['description'],re.UNICODE).group()
```

Returns None.

Comment: Did you really mean to have `r'.'` as the first argument to `re.match`?

Comment: Yes. Is that not okay? I would of course like to do more complex matching, but I can't even get this working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what `r` in front of a string literal does in python. What's it supposed to mean?

Comment: And what are you trying to extract from the string with your regular expression?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin `r` in front of a string literal in Python allows you to enter backslashes without escaping them, which is useful for regexes.

Comment: more info on raw string notation in regular expressions here http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague . I am just trying to be in the habit.

Comment: @buck54321 Can you give an example of a url for which you are having problems?

Comment: http://www.johnnyseeds.com/p-5522-red-ace-f1-og.aspx

Comment: @buck54321 What happens if you replace `re.match` with `re.search`? (Sorry, I'd try myself, but I don't have Python 2 on this machine, and I can't reproduce this in Python 3, leading me to believe that this is Python 2-specific.)

Comment: That works fine. I can work with that. Still not sure why above code doesn't work.

Comment: I thought the only difference between match and search was whether you had to match from the beginning of the string.  But this regex matches any char. What an I missing!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's probably what's going on (but I haven't checked to see if this is actually the case, since I don't have Python 2 on my machine and can't reproduce this in Python 3). If you look at the docs for [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), you find that it reads:

> `re.match`(*pattern*, *string*, *flags=0*)
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of *string* match the regular expression *pattern*, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance. Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Important point: `re.match` only matches at the *beginning* of a string.

Next, the dot character `.`:

> `'.'`
>
> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the `DOTALL` flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

So, `.` doesn't match newlines. Therein lies the problem - if `info['description']` begins with a newline, you will not get a match.

What you should do is either use `re.search` or pass in the `re.DOTALL` flag to `re.match`.